# Thermal imaging camera always blurry. Expected?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I bought a cheap thermal imaging camera for establishing hotspots in a circuit to see if any components get near or above maximum rated temperature.

But...

1. even though some hot spots should be very clear and distinct, they appear blurry.
2. Those small hot spots' temperatures seem to be hotter than the camera indicates.

Are these expected phenomena? Or is the camera cheap/inappropriate? It has 60x60 pixel, 20 degree FOV and a fixed 50cm focal distance, so really it should be ideal? Cheapest on the market but excellent reviews.

I wonder if conduction, convection and radiation mean the radiation received by the camera will always appear blurry? (Because either the heat actually is distributing itself in the circuitboard) or the radiation diffuses (so to speak) in the air before it reaches the camera? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Edit: thanks for responses. Please see images below:

[image]
[image]

The hot component is the transistor attached to the heatsink.

It looks to me like upscaling is not the issue? Nor the limited resolution? The thermal images in sales material for this and other models look crisp in comparison, so I'm leaning towards getting a refund, something seems wrong.

The model is [KKMoon 3600](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KKmoon-Thermometer-Temperature-Real-Time-Resolution/dp/B074QMHJYX/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1519182493&sr=8-10&keywords=Thermal%20camera)

Comment: So what model is that and at what distance from the hot spots do you use it?

Comment: The thermal radiation is not directional. A significant portion of it will hit board. The surface layer of the board is probably non-reflective, not particularly good at conducting heat and fairly flat. It will heat up until the heat it absorbs is radiated, conducted or convected away. Since as mentioned above it is probably good at absorbing and bad at conducting and convecting the heat away...

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the $60 \times 60$ pixel resolution is limiting. Maybe you do not see the squares in the images on your display, but the result of software interpolation to a larger number of pixels. This looks blurry.

Also, when your small hot spot is smaller than the area imaged onto a single pixel, the signal from that pixel will underestimate to temperature of the hot spot. You can estimate the minimum size by doing some geometry.

Answer (score 0):

There may be different causes of the problem. You did not answer from what distance you took the images. They say the shortest focal distance is 0.5 m. I don't quite understand that, but suspect this is the shortest distance from which you can take focused images (assuming that the focus is adjustable; but you say the focal distance is fixed?). So you should probably take pictures from this distance. However, I suspect you used a larger distance: the image occupies a small part of your screen. For the distance of 50 cm and FOV of 20 deg, the object covering the entire screen is about 17 cm (20 deg is approximately 1/3 radian), therefore, 1 pixel corresponds to 1/60 of that, i.e., about 0.3 cm. Thus, in principle, the resolution that you can achieve is not bad. On the other hand, maybe the heatsink works too well :-), so the heat is distributed over the heatsink, or the hot spots can be obstructed by something (your visible image is not detailed enough to see).

I don't think the camera is too cheap, but you can get something better in this price range if you choose an add-on for a smartphone, such as seek compact xr (https://www.thermal.com/compact-series.html ; maybe there are newer and better gadgets now). We used it to make pictures of an 11 micron carbon fiber heated by a microwave beam. The minimum distance for the camera is 15 cm, if I am not mistaken, so 1 pixel corresponds to about 250 micron of the object, so the thermal image is heavily averaged. See an example below (the camera probably "sees" not only the fiber but also heated air near the fiber).

[image]

So maybe you should try your camera with an object where you have a better idea of what can be achieved in principle, for example, candle flame of heated nichrome wire.